# Joomla not showing template

Tags: joomla

I am experimenting with Joomla 3.1.4. Whenever I add a new module the template does not show at all in the front-end. The site is blank. On disabling the new module it starts showing properly again. Even a basic hello world type of module does not seem to work and nor does a third party extension I have tried. I can see them in the extension manager and in the module manager and they have installed successfully. Frustrated with all this I decided to install a new 3.1 template which too installed successfully. However this template does not show anything in the front-end either with my module enabled. It almost seems that there is some sort of security restriction which is disabling the template from rendering whenever any change is made to the basic installation. Can someone please give pointers to resolving this odd behaviour.

Comment: Have you tried enabling error reporting? A blank screen indicates a fatal error in the module's code.

Comment: Post your module code

Answer (score 2):

Try with another module and check again.

In your module have some problem so the theme not displayed properly.

In joomla 3.0 have some errors with modules and templates when you use virtuemart it has many error occured.

Comment: I tried with another module. Although it is not giving total blank but it is not displaying the module despite being published. It seems odd that a rogue module can make the whole site die rather than just that particular module. I think I will wait for a while before v3.1 becomes totally stable before using it.

Comment: Sure Please try to reinstall your joomla3.1 and again try i think your problem is solved with this

Comment: Any module will contain PHP code and any PHP code can kill the whole site.  It cannot be contained purely to that module as the code could do absolutely anything.  Which is what you want it to be able to do so you can have cool modules.  But also the danger, so you should only install reputable modules that are not on the vulnerability list.  If you are creating your own module or hello world, I would suspect you have made an error somewhere.  It would be good if you posted that code so we could troubleshoot the module code in question as that is the way we would find this problem.